# File creation function in Python

Tags: python, file, io

Does `open()` in python create a file? If not, is there a function that does that? When I use this, it gives me

> "IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/home/sanjiv/Desktop/COSURP/pyfiles/f1.txt'"

Was I not supposed to put the location to create the file? If not, where does it create it

```
f = open('/home/sanjiv/Desktop/COSURP/pyfiles/f1.txt', 'r+')
gpa = {'fall15':4.0, 'spr16':3.47, 'fall16':4.0}
for s in gpa:
    f.write(str(s) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Does the directory already exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to open the file for writing you should use the `w` as the second parameter (of the `open` function), and not `r+`.

The `w` will open the file for writing (and **truncating** the file if it already exists):

```
f = open('/home/sanjiv/Desktop/COSURP/pyfiles/f1.txt', 'w')
gpa = {'fall15':4.0, 'spr16':3.47, 'fall16':4.0}
for s in gpa:
    f.write(str(s) + '\n')
f.close()
```

> Note that if you want to open a file in the directory `/home/sanjiv/Desktop/COSURP/pyfiles/` this directory **must** exists and you **must** have write-permissions to this directory.

Comment: The file does not exist initially. That worked! Thanks!